# RichTextBox (How to edit the format similar to notepad?)

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I just started using Richtextboxes for copying my whole text file to my RTB in a window,

My question is, how to format it in a way that uses 1 character per cell format similar to notepad? The only line of code i use to place the text in RTB is :

```
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(@fileLocation);
```

I tested by editing font in properties but it does not help

My program in RTB currently looks like it is from a microsoft word formating where the space consumed by the letter 'i' is different from the letter 'O'

Thanks and cheers to all who can help

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for a *fixed pitch* font.  One that uses the same amount of space for every glyph.

There are not many to choose from, most machines have only a few installed.  Change the Font property and pick Courier New, Consolas or Lucida Sans.

Comment: Wow thanks that helped a lot! The fonts i tried are not of fixed pitch font =)